# Images with Base64 Automatism - Javascript (with PHP?)

Tags: javascript, image, base64

I heard a lot about Baase64 Encoding for Images in Webdesign.

And i saw a lot of developers they use it for thier headlines with: `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0...`

Is there any automatism (with javascript) behind?
Or have they all converted & inserted ? (could not belive)

Example: http://obox-inkdrop.tumblr.com/ (- Headlines)

Comment: Do you mean "animation" (rather than "automatism")?

Comment: The example you linked does not use data-URIs but [cufón](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) to replace the text by some kind of image.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the encoding has to be done on the server-side, be it :

- automated with a script, that reads the original image file, and returns the base64 encoded string to inject it into the HTML that's being generated
- or by hand, and directly placed into the HTML.

The base64 encoding cannot be done on the client-side, as the goal is to avoid sending the image file from the server to the browser *(to minimize the number of HTTP requests)*.

Depending of the language that's used on the server-side, you'll probably find some function to do base64 encoding.

In PHP, you might be interested by [**`base64_encode()`**](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.base64-encode.php)

Comment: What is about canvas - HTML5 ?